# Replace portion of URL in .htaccess and preserve query string

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I sent an email out to *lots* of people with the wrong URL and need to fix it with .htaccess. The wrong URL:

```
https://amemoirproject.com/chapters/leaving-tanglewood/?utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Chapter+15+The+Anointed&utm_content=Chapter+15+The+Anointed+CID_6d1662ca75fabbdcbd66397fc00cdcf4&utm_source=Campaign%20Monitor&utm_term=Chapter%2015%20The%20Anointed%20%20A%20Long-Haired%20Handsome%20Jesus
```

The correct URL:

```
https://amemoirproject.com/chapters/the-anointed/?utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Chapter+15+The+Anointed&utm_content=Chapter+15+The+Anointed+CID_6d1662ca75fabbdcbd66397fc00cdcf4&utm_source=Campaign%20Monitor&utm_term=Chapter%2015%20The%20Anointed%20%20A%20Long-Haired%20Handsome%20Jesus
```

The only difference is the change of the directory from `leaving-tanglewood` to `the-anointed`. I need to retain the query string, and this should be a 302.

Suggestions?

**EDIT**

This 302 redirect should only occur if the original incorrect URL contains the following query parameter and value:

```
utm_campaign=Chapter+15+The+Anointed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)utm_campaign=Chapter\+15\+The\+Anointed(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(chapters)/leaving-tanglewood/?$ /$1/the-anointed/ [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Would you use the QSA flag in this instance?

Comment: @miah: QSA is not really needed for this case since we are not adding anything to existing QUERY_STRING. Existing QUERY_STRING will be rewritten *as is* to target URI.

Comment: So sorry. I forgot to mention that this 302 redirect should only occur if the query string contains this parameter and value: `utm_campaign=Chapter+15+The+Anointed`