# Regular Expression to capture URLs with ascii encoded characters

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Having migrated a Wordpress site to a new build, I need to capture a lot of old URLs and redirect them to the same content on the new site. The problem is that the old site has a lot of URLs with ascii-encoded chars and Wordpress has stripped them out on the current site. For example:

```
/blog/uncategorized/germany%E2%80%99s-ageing-population-working-longer-working-better.html
```

would redirect to:

```
/blog/germanys-ageing-population-working-longer-working-better/
```

Can anyone provide a regular expression that would remove the ascii-encoded characters?

Comment: What are you using to do the string replacement?

Comment: I'm using a plugin but it's basically a .htaccess 301 redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to match against the request here, because with redirect and rewrite rules, the URI is *decoded* before the patterns get applied. That means you'd be matching against stuff like `â` instead of the encoded strings. So you'll want something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /blog/([^\?\ ]*)\%[A-Z0-9]{2}([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /blog/%1%2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Answer (score 3):

For matching the encoded characters, you would use the following regex pattern:

```
%[A-Z0-9]{2}
```

How you perform the replacement will depend on the language/tool you are using.

Comment: How would I do this in a .htaccess?

Comment: I don't have that answer for you, but try looking at some other questions on the site, like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316152/replace-portion-of-url-in-htaccess-and-preserve-query-string